# $\dot{x_1} error while using in matrix

Tags: matrices

While creating a matrix by using

```
$
\begin{matrix}
 $\dot{x_1}$ \\
 $\dot{x_2}$ \\
\end{matrix}
$
```

How to get the required output?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: "How to get the required output?" That of course depends on the required output. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: One error here are the `$` inside matrix. They should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The cells in the matrix are already in math mode. An additional `$` leaves math and `\dot` will cause the error. Try:

```
$
\begin{matrix}
  \dot{x_1} \\
  \dot{x_2} \\
\end{matrix}
$
```

Full example with a version, where the dot is applied to the letter directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
\begin{matrix}
  \dot{x_1} \\
  \dot{x_2} \\
\end{matrix}
$ vs.\@
$
\begin{matrix}
  \dot{x}_1 \\
  \dot{x}_2 \\
\end{matrix}
$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]